# Telewag: a form for transportation?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I want to make use of alliteration while writing the heading for an article on Transportation (describing what the future transportation has in store for us etc.) i.e

"Transportation T______"  OR "T______ Transportation" either way.

While searching, I came across this word,

> **[Telewag](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/79136/40-tremendous-t-words-titivate-your-vocabulary)** - An old English dialect word for a telegram

I want to know whether the following headings,

- `Telewagging Transportation` or
- `Transport Telewag`

will convey the right meaning to the reader?

Comment: I doubt ***telewag*** ever had as much currency as people writing books about "interesting" dialectal usage would like to imply (I've never seen it before). Certainly it wouldn't convey anything to most readers, so I suggest you avoid it like the plague. Especially in a collocation with "transportation" - even after checking how ***telewag*** has been used in print through Google Books, I have no idea what you're trying to convey with the term. And as a general principle, if you're not a native Anglophone you should probably avoid "playing" with the language like this.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for letting me know this. But then, how would you suggest to go by making use of aliteration? Also, does headings always need to make sense? Does a `fancy` heading be overlooked, like the two mentioned?

Comment: Headings don't necessarily need to be *grammatically valid*, but it's important that they should be *meaningful* to your readers. Given the existence of slangy / colloquial ***chinwag*** (universally familiar to Anglophones), I can see it might be "nice, clever" to use ***telewag*** in your context, ***if you could reasonably expect it  to be understood***. But there isn't much chance of that, so imho it's a bad idea. I advise you to strive for "clarity", not "cleverness".

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers for taking out time to explain me. I shall be back with a good question next time soon. Thanks

Comment: I have never come across it either. How informal is the piece? "Transportation Tattle" could be ok if it's a light gossipy piece.

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine: Nice one! But you counld go the whole "alliteration" hog with *Transportation **Tittle-Tattle**!*

Comment: Hi @BeginTheBeguine, I am actually skimming through the latest current innovation and technological advancement in Transportation sector. Through this article I want to highlight the role of several engineering disciplines to fascinate the bright hardworking undergrads apart from their semeseter course load.

Comment: A bit weird that the OP doesn't seem to have considered Telegram or Telegraph; the latter is commonly used for the name of newspapers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telewag is so obscure that it doesn't convey anything to anyone these days.

Figures of speech are used to masterfully play with words, but such decoration is a secondary consideration. Conveying whatever you want to convey is always more important. For example something like "Travel Travails" would be a fun alliteration to use for an article about a tough journey.

Tomorrow's Transport, Thoughts on Transportation, these might be more suitable for the article you had in mind.

Comment: amazing, exactly what I could not think by self! Going with Tomorrow's Transportation. Thank you @Pranab